# train() function and rate model (poisson regression with offset) with caret

Tags: r, glm, r-caret, cross-validation

I fitted a rate model using `glm()` (poisson link with offset, like

```
y ~ offset(log(x1)) + x2 + x3
```

the response is `y/x1` in this case).

Then I wanted to do cross validation using **caret** package so I used 'train()' function with *k*-fold CV control. It turns out the 2 models I have are very different. It seems that `train()` can't handle `offset`: I change the variable within `offset` to be `offset(log(log(x1))` or `offset(log(sqrt(x1))`, the models remain the same.

Any one have this kind of experience before and how did you deal with it? 
Thanks!

btw I want to save the prediction on each validation set so so far I only know caret can do that, thats why I didnt choose to use cv.glm.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot claim to have prior experience with this exact process, and have not done any testing in the absence of you offering a reproducible example and code. But I do have experience with moving offsets to the LHS of a `glm`-Poission regression call, so why not change the formula (and family) to:

```
 glm( I(y/x1) ~ x2 + x3, family=quasipoisson, data= , ...)
```

Comment: hmmm I dont think the log link function would work since the response gonna have a lot of zeros...

Comment: Hmmm, indeed. You are the one who was proposing using `offset(log(x1))` AND you offered no test dataset, so how were we supposed to have anticipated this concern???